# how to access email subfolders?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to access subfolder of an email and retrieve all the messages inside it programmatically.

I am using POP3 server.

preferably to be in VB.net or in C# and preferably with as little third party libraries as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I just want to know how it can be done, Like I want to access a sub folder "eg: inbox > subfolder1" and get all the emails inside this folder, currently all I can do is to list all emails recieved regardless of their folder.